# forcing only one instance of Asyc sub

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, vsto

I'd like to trigger a slow-running sub when particular emails arrive, but I don't want to block execution/freeze outlook.

I've written the sub as `Public Async Sub...` but part of the code would fall over if the sub was called twice in quick succession.

Is there any way to make a queue such that only one copy of my sub is running at any one time, while ensuring that it's still running in the background?

My solution at the moment is to have a public `continue as Boolean` with a waiting loop beforehand - but this is a bit on the ugly side!

Comment: Maybe use a [SyncLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement)?

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do it (which would necessarily involve locks).  Be very very careful, though, because if you get the locks wrong, you risk deadlocking your app.  My thoughts run more toward having a single processing queue, so that subsequent attempts to run notice that it's already running, add their work to the processing queue, and return.